# I'm having problems locating the FAB icon over the toolbar in angular material

Tags: angular-material

I'm having trouble positioning the angular material FAB button over the toolbar.

[image: angular material FAB button positioning]

Although my z-index in the FAB icon is greater than the one on the toolbar. Any thoughts?

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl" ng-cloak="" class="toolbardemoBasicUsage" ng-app="MyApp">
  <md-content>
    <md-toolbar class="md-tall md-accent">
      <h2 class="md-toolbar-tools">
        <span>Toolbar: tall (md-accent)</span>
      </h2>
    </md-toolbar>
    <md-content>
      <md-button class="md-fab my-fab-element" aria-label="Some content">
        +
    </md-button>
  </md-content>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.toolbardemoBasicUsage md-toolbar md-icon.md-default-theme {
  color: white;
}

md-content {
  position: relative;
}

.my-fab-element {
    right: 0;
    top: -35px;
    background: green !important;
}
```

DEMO

http://codepen.io/pennybirman/pen/NbjRNw

Comment: Please, add some code to help us find the problem or even better, some demo (code snippet, codepen, jsfiddle, plunker)

Comment: Here is a codepen. The FAB icon should be display over the toolbar.

Comment: [link](http://codepen.io/pennybirman/pen/NbjRNw)

Comment: ok, please check my answer below. Next time please remember to attach your code and demo in your question!

Comment: @PennyBirman The linked demo appears to be different than the screenshot that you provided.

Answer (score 0):

FAB goes beyond the `md-content`, and its `overflow` is set to `auto`, I think you should change it to `overflow: visible`

CSS:

```
md-content {
  position: relative;
  overflow: visible;
}
```